# Why does the servlet API throw IllegalStateException on forwarding a request after writing to the response?

Tags: servlets

What is the rationale for this exception on forwarding of the request. The reason behind the exception on response.redirect is that a 30x redirect response header can't be issued after some of the response body has been flushed to the output stream. But I don't see the reason for doing this on an internal forward.

The use case I have in mind is to early flush the html  content from filters so the browser can get a head start (pun intended) on the top css and javascript while the servlet does its backend work before handing off to a presentation jsp. By yielding the first byte sooner, I'm hoping to see a client side performance benefit.

Struts and other frameworks depend on forward dispatches. It is because of these forwards that we can't flush response content early, according to the API.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, imagine the case when you send some `<head>` definitions to the browser, and then forward to a page that is completely different. The result will be some messed-up page. With (perhaps) two `<head>` sections, one of which is irrelevant.

You can use `requestDispatcher.include(..)` in order to include the result of a different page, rather than forward to it.

Comment: Thanks for the good example. Is that typically the case, forwarding to a "different" page, or would you normally forward to complete a page for a given request? I see how you could get yourself in trouble, but it doesn't seem to necessitate an IllegalStateException, as it could result in a perfectly valid outcome, unlike the redirect after committing case, which is always invalid.  Your explanation seems fair, though the rule does seem a bit over-strict to me

Comment: @Joe Hanink - the servlet container cannot determine whether the ouput is valid or not. Hence it reports a problem always. See my update btw

Comment: that is true, but it is not valid or invalid in virtue of the forward, but due to the content. I could just as easily jsp:include <head> content twice. I suppose the servlet API authors are erring on the side of safety where they can, but it seems that there is a major distinction between page-level content control and http header integrity. It seems response redirects after response committal is a true API level illegal state, whereas multiply including a <head> tag is just an application-level programming mistake. At any rate, thanks for your input. It's as good an explanation as any.